# Excel VBA: Compute Age with the leap years that have passed

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compute age from a given birthdate. My problem is my code produce an inaccurate result 'cause the leap years aren't included in my equation. How do I solve that?

```
Dim bday As String
bday = UserForm.Birthdate.Value 
UserForm.Age.Value = (Date - DateValue(bday)) / 365
```

Comment: Use Excels built in function for calculating the difference - leap years will then be considered during the calculation.  
`=DATEDIF(BirthDate,TODAY(),"y")&" years "&DATEDIF(BirthDate,TODAY(),"ym")&" months "&DATEDIF(BirthDate,TODAY(),"md")&" days" ` (from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx).

Comment: VBA versions are available:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm

Comment: Interestingly DateDif Formula does not have WorksheetFunction in VBA so you should use custom VBA code if you have to use VBA rather than Excel formula

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Much easier to troubleshoot if you demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @ChrisHarper VBA has a similar `DateDiff` function.  And also, if you must (and it is rarely necessary), you can always use the `Evaluate` function to run Excel functions that are not part of the `WorksheetFunction` collection.

Answer (score 0):

For your case I would use Excels function [DateDiff](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php), to return the difference between two dates

You would use it in this way:

`UserForm.Age.Value = DateDiff("yyyy", date, datevalue(bday))`

Comment: The result is off by a year.

Comment: @HydesYase What are your inputs, actual outputs and desired outputs. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The input is a birthdate. The actual output is the computed age but is inaccurate because the leap years are not included in the computation. My desired output is an accurate result where the leap years are included in the computation.

Comment: @HydesYase I cannot reproduce your problem from the data you have provided. If I enter a birthdate and today's date, I get the correct result. Ergo, there is something special about your data, which you refuse to supply, or you are applying the recommended solutions incorrectly.